# Fatal Memory Error Solspace FreeForm

Tags: solspace-freeform, memory-limit

I have a site with a simple form on it 9 fields total. It has worked fine for quite some time but is now up to 2875 responses. I am getting the following error and the site is not coming up.

Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 267409 bytes) in ...../expressionengine/third_party/freeform/mod.freeform.php on line 4138

I have the contacted the host about raising the memory_limit but I am wondering if anyone else has come across this. It doesn't seem like enough responses to cause memory issues. In the template I am calling up and displaying all the response names (its a petition).

EE 2.9.0 with Freeform 4.2.3 Current memory is set to 128M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yah, that'll do it. Remember that you aren't storing that data raw, PHP variables take up more space than their raw data.

Get your memory raised, or you can temporarily do it yourself. Add this to your sites index.php file (the one in your web root):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```